# amcharts 4 cursor and mouse positioning not correct

Tags: angular, amcharts4

I have an angular 7 app that I am working on and don't have any issues with the chart.cursor on any other chart series except LineChart (using grouping). There seems to be an odd gap between the location of mouse and the cursor/data point it is snapping to. The gap seems to be at the bottom and right of the mouse.

The further to the right/bottom of the chart I move, the larger the gap gets, and vice versa, top/left it gets smaller. I cannot replicate this in [codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrUo8.png), but noticed that the data point is not aligned with the dataAxis the more I zoom in.

Is there a way to handle these gaps, or be able to use just the mouse position to interact with the chart without using a cursor? Also, just in case this is useful, it is displayed within a MatDialog.

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/TheProfessor84/pen/abzJPQP

Comment: Apparently adding a small timeout got it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the ngAfterViewInit and giving it a small timeout, seemed to correct the issue. I am guessing that the timing of loading the chart within the dialog loading had an offset of where the mouse was when each item was loading and the difference was the gap.

Comment: timeout does not work for me,
I currently have to use a workaround:

chart.cursor.dx = -44;

Comment: what worked for me was to remove all unneeded CSS. I first placed the charts in an empty HTML page, and have seen the charts with the correct mouse/cursor position/alignment. Then I started to remove all CSS from the view that had the charts. 
Now it works well, and lots of ugly CSS are gone for good. :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to get the chart to fill its entire container. I think because it was a flexbox, I had to manually change the chart's size, and was doing it like this:

```js
this.root = am5.Root.new('chart-id', {
  calculateSize: function (dimensions) {
    return {
      width:
        (document.getElementById('chart-id')?.clientWidth as number) *
        0.9,
      height:
        (document.getElementById('chart-id')?.clientHeight as number) *
        0.9,
    };
  },
});
```

But that led to a chart cursor/actual mouse cursor offset.

---

To fix this, I changed to doing this:

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const self = this;
  am5.ready(function () {
    timer(100).subscribe((x) => {
      self.initChart();
    });
  });
}

private initChart() {
  this.root = am5.Root.new('chart-id');
  this.root._inner.setAttribute('height', '100%');
  this.root._inner.setAttribute('width', '100%');
}
```

As far as I can tell, the timer is necessary because otherwise the chart doesn't fill the entire container. This solution makes the chart take up the full container without causing any cursor offset.